# Latex bracket on multiple lines

Tags: brackets

[image]

How can I code the equations with big brackets on the right and left sides shown in the picture? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This probably have to be done via tikz with some tikzmarks and decorations.

Comment: @daleif I not will make surely with Mathcha. :-) :-)

Comment: `nicematrix` is good candidate ...

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works because `stackengine` can set equations with fixed baselineskip.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\TABstackMath
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
%\setstackgap{L}{1.1\baselineskip}% VERTICAL SPACING OF CENTER EQUATIONS
%\renewcommand\stacktype{L}% GIVES LEFT/RIGHT EQS SAME VERTICAL SPACING AS CENTER EQS
\Centerstack{
\\
\\
\alignstackanchor{a=&b}{a=&b}{\left\{\begin{aligned}\\\\\end{aligned}\right.}\\
\\
\\
\alignstackanchor{a=&b}{a=&b}{\left\{\begin{aligned}\\\\\end{aligned}\right.}\\
\\
}
\alignCenterstack{
a=&b\\
a=&b\\
a=&b\\
a=&b\\
a=&b\\
a=&b\\
a=&b\\
a=&b
}
\Centerstack{
\smash{\phantom{\left.\begin{aligned}\\\\\end{aligned}\right\}}}a = b\\
\\
\\
{\left.\begin{aligned}\\\\\end{aligned}\right\}}\alignstackanchor{a=&b}{a=&b}\\
\\
\\
{\left.\begin{aligned}\\\\\end{aligned}\right\}}\alignstackanchor{a=&b}{a=&b}\\
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent as usual :-) I had not understood the picture.

Comment: Wow...No words to express....Great....

Answer (score 11):

A solution with `bigdelim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, bigdelim} 

\begin{document}


\[\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} \begin{array}{c@{\,}c@{\enspace}c }
 & a = b & a = b \\
 \ldelim\{{3}{*}[$ \begin{gathered}
 a = b \\ a = b
\end{gathered} $ ] & a = b \\
& a = b & \rdelim\}{3}{*} [$ \begin{gathered}
 a = b \\ a = b
\end{gathered} $ ]\\
  & a = b \\
\ldelim\{{3}{*}[$ \begin{gathered}
a = b \\ a = b
\end{gathered} $ ] & a = b \\
  & a = b \\
  & a = b \\
  & a = b \\
\end{array} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This also wonderful....You all are great ....

Answer (score 3):

Just a small try, but `Steven B. Segletes` answer is 100 times better than mine, here is the `MWE` for my try:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
&$\begin{matrix}
a=b\\
a=b
\end{matrix}$ &$a=b$\\
$\begin{matrix}
a=b\\
a=b
\end{matrix}$ &\multirow{-2}{*}{\Bigg\{} $\begin{matrix}
a=b\\
a=b
\end{matrix}$ &\multirow{2}{*}{\Bigg\}} $\begin{matrix}
a=b\\
a=b
\end{matrix}$\\[19pt]
$\begin{matrix}
a=b\\
a=b
\end{matrix}$ &\multirow{-2}{*}{\Bigg\{} $\begin{matrix}
a=b\\
a=b\\
a=b\\
a=b
\end{matrix}$ &\multirow{2}{*}{\Bigg\}} $\begin{matrix}
a=b\\
a=b
\end{matrix}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not really true. You should fix it because it not specular to the image. See better the output. :)

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, when I saw the answer from `Steven` then just I stopped working, should improve my knowledge....

Comment: Each of us has its own human, personal, logical, etc.. You also have the humility to recognize your limits, like me who knows my limits. Slowly you will also learn.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} 
\begin{NiceArray}{c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c}
& a=b & a=b \\
\Block{3-1}{\begin{gathered}a=b\\ a=b\end{gathered}}
& a=b \\
& a=b & \Block{3-1}{\begin{gathered}a=b\\ a=b\end{gathered}}\\
& a=b \\
\Block{3-1}{\begin{gathered}a=b\\ a=b\end{gathered}}
& a=b \\
& a=b \\
& a=b \\
& a=b \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{\lbrace}{2-2}{4-2}{.}
  \SubMatrix{.}{3-2}{5-2}{\rbrace}
  \SubMatrix{\lbrace}{5-2}{7-2}{.}
\end{NiceArray} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]